# Rearrangement of functional groups in chemical names using regular expression in R

Tags: regex, string, r

Earlier I was using the following method to move functional groups mentioned at the end of a chemical 
name (separated with one or more ", ") to the front:

```
name <- "2,6-Octadien-1-ol, 3,7-dimethyl-, (E)-"

paste(rev(strsplit(name, ", ")[[1]]), collapse = "")
[1] "(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol"
```

I now have some cases where a "," is used as a separator rather than a ", ". Anybody any thoughts how I should fix such names?

E.g.

```
name <- "2,6-Octadien-1-ol,3,7-dimethyl-,(E)-"
```

should yield

```
"(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol"
```

I was thinking in this case to break at comma's if these comma's do not come after a number (or "(" or ")" brackets). But what regular expression should I use in `strsplit` to achieve this? Or how could one specify a regular expression that breaks either at a ", " or at a comma that does not follow a number (or "(" or ")" brackets)?

Comment: replace a space for nothing first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name <- "2,6-Octadien-1-ol, 3,7-dimethyl-, (E)-"
name = gsub("(\\D),","\\1#",gsub(" ","",name))
paste(rev(strsplit(name, "#")[[1]]), collapse = "")
```

This assumes any non-digit followed by a comma is a real seperator, the other commas are part of a name.

Comment: Ha sorry been too quick - there are also cases like name <- "1-Propene,1,1'-oxybis-,(E,E)-" which should yield "(E,E)-1,1'-oxybis-1-Propene" - so I think the rule should be that any comma that follows a small caps letter or a "-" should be a separator.

Comment: change the middle one to: `name = gsub("([a-z]|-),","\\1#",gsub(" ","",name))`